# URL amigavel no scope

Tags: html, angularjs

Como posso passar:

```
categoryId=101010&subcategoryId=1210101020&priceMin=1000&priceMax=3000
```

Para:

```
/tv/smart-tv/1000/3000 no $scope?
```